# Estimating comparative success of different brochures

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, statistical-significance

### The Real World Problem

One of my clients is preparing to send a direct mailer to their subscribed user list, and this statistical challenge came up.

Their marketing team has 3 different brochures, and wants to know which brochure gets the highest response rate.  They would also like to know if sending the mailer with a hand-written address, on a thick envelope, improves results compared to a normal envelope.

Let's assume the following:

- For each brochure $b_i$ ($i = 1,2,3$), a person receiving that brochure *who actually opens it and reads it* will respond with probability $r_i$, where $r_i$ is the true response rate for that brochure
- The thick, high-quality envelopes have a true open rate of $o_{thick}$ while normal envelopes have an open rate of $o_{normal}$
- From previous mailings, we expect actual observed response rates will be between approximately 1% and 5%.

### Our Goals

We want to find the best brochure while sending the fewest number of mailers.  We also want to estimate the two open rates.

Upon gathering empirical response rates from actual sent mailers, if the true difference between response rates $r_i$ is greater than half a percent, we should be able to detect that difference as statisitcally significant with $p < .05$

### My thoughts so far

We randomly assign users to each of the 3 brochures, such that $N$ users receive each brochure.  We want to know what $N$ we need to achieve our desired sensitivity in detecting differences in response rates.  Assuming the worst case, we need to be able to detect a difference between true rates of 1% and 1.5%.  The SD for this difference is $\sqrt{\frac{(.01*.99) + (.015*.985)}{N}}$.  Setting twice that quantity (2 standard deviations gives us 95% confidence) equal to .005 (our desired half a percent) leads to the solution $N = 3948$.

### Questions

- Is this the optimal design or can we do better?
- Is my calculation of $N$ correct?

Finally, what is the best way to estimate $o_{normal}$ and $o_{thick}$, or simply the difference between the two?

My idea was to randomly assign half of each brochure group to each type of envelope.  Within each brochure group, the observed response rates would be the product of the open rates and the $r_i$.  This would complicate my calculation of $N$ above, since really I should have used this product in my calculation.

My answer would then depend on an estimate of the average open rate -- $\frac{o_{normal} + o_{thick}}{2}$ -- which I'd have to guess at.  Also, I am not sure how to determine the distribution of the difference between $o_{normal}$ and $o_{thick}$, since we now have three different estimates of that difference, each of which depends on a different $r_i$, each of which we have only empirical estimates of, empirical estimates which themselves depend on our guess at the average open rate.

Thanks very much for any help with this.

Comment: Here is a thought experiment to consider before going too much further: Assume two scenarios, A and B. In scenario A, each recipient receives their mail, opens it, then flips a coin with probability $r_i$ to decide whether to respond. In Scenario B, your recipients look at the mail they receive, flip a coin with probability $r_i$, and open the mail if it comes up heads; they eagerly respond to any offers contained in the mail they open and discard any mail they don't open.

Comment: hey cardinal, my thought is that the most accurate model is actually a hybrid of A and B.  Think about how you actual deal with junk mail.  Personally, based on the envelope and postmark, I will simply throw away most of it unopened.  But if I do open it, the marketing inside then needs to grab my attention and convince me.  If we think of our mailer as a hero on a quest, he must slay two independent dragons to save the princess.  And as test designers, we are trying to measure the relative fitness of different heros at the task of slaying these 2 different dragons.

Comment: I agree that people generally don't act so extreme, but the point of introducing the scenarios was to provoke some thought about what can and can't be estimated from your data (without introducing additional implicit, and potentially quite strong, assumptions). In one scenario the observed response rate comes entirely from a random response decision whereas in the second it comes entirely from a random mail opening decision!

Comment: Well I think the simpler model your thought experiment suggests leads to a problem that's much easier to solve.  I can simply think about testing 6 scenarios (each envelope with each brochure) and test for differences using a method similar to the one in the "My thoughts..." section.  But I suspect that will lead to sending more mailers than a solution to the more complex two-tiered model.  The problem is I don't know what distribution that two-tiered model gives rise to, so I don't know how to test it -- hence the post :)

Answer (score 1):

There are empirical formulas for determining the sample size. The underlying test is a two-sample **t test** for equality of the metric( response rate in your case). Assuming that you want the power of the test to be 80%, one such formula is $n= 16\sigma^2/\Delta^2$ where $\sigma$ is the std dev of the metric ( response rate) and $\Delta$ is the amount of change in the response rate that you want to resolve reliably ( with statistical significance).

Also, there are fractional factorial designs available which let you optimize the number of trials (assuming you don't want to measure interactions of each factor with every other factor). This is a  [survey paper on experimental design](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ronnyk/2009controlledExperimentsOnTheWebSurvey.pdf) that describes the details.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you sent brochures $A$ and $B$ to **equal number of customers**, then $a$ users respond to brochure $A$, and $b$ users respond to brochure $B$, and $b>a$.  Then the significance is

$P = {\sum_{n=b}^{a+b} C^{a+b}_n \over 2^{a+b}}$

It doesn't matter how many users received your brochures, just how many responded.